# Highcharts chart resize on window resize event after setting a specific size

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In an app that I work I have this scenario:
In a responsive container I have a chart. This container is resized at a point and I need to change the chart size by calling the `setSize` method.
But after that I want to make the chart responsive again - to resize on window resize event.

I made a fiddle to demo this:
http://jsfiddle.net/7ka4qaef/
First click on the red button, then try to resize the window.
Is there anyway to 'forget' that I've used `setSize` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this after your setSize does what you want:

```js
$('#container').highcharts().hasUserSize = false;
```

[Forked JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2j2b61z/)

previous query on this: [stackoverflow query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345256/is-modifying-chart-hasusersize-a-bad-idea-after-calling-chart-setsize)

Answer (score 0):

`hasUserSize` has been removed in newest version of HighCharts.

I managed to do the same with these lines:

```
chart.options.chart.width = null;
chart.options.chart.height = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

i use [update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.update) function to solve this problem.

```
this.$refs.highcharts.chart.update({
  chart: {
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
  },
});
```