# How to revert/reverse/undo setSize() in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, revert

Question asked because I spent a while trying to solve this and the answer isn't easily Google-able:

If I've manually set the size of a chart how do I make it go back to how it was before I did so?
(Question left deliberately ambiguous as I have found two distinct answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to do one of 2 things:

1. Go back to the previous fixed size.
2. Go back to the size being variable according the size of the containing element.

For #1, you can collect (and thus store for later resetting) the current size of the chart BEFORE you call the `setSize()` by calling `chart.chartHeight` or `chart.chartWidth` (where `var chart = $('#chart-container').highcharts();`), then just call `setSize()` again with the original values.

For #2, after you've called setSize() post-print, the chart will no-longer auto-size itself if the window changes. You can fix that by using the 'hack' detailed here: [Is modifying chart.hasUserSize a bad idea after calling Chart.setSize()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345256/is-modifying-chart-hasusersize-a-bad-idea-after-calling-chart-setsize)
Which consists of setting `chart.hasUserSize = false;`